# How to get originals date and time in java

Tags: java

Actually

```
Date date = new Date();
```

will give us date of that server where application is running.
if particular server has set date and time wrong in that case how we can get real date and time?

Comment: Using a web service I suppose. But then you must account for latency.

Comment: Does 'wrong' mean times zones are unaccounted for, or it's just completely incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not worry to much about the server's correct date. I mean a server is usually administrated by you, so just set the time correctly or use [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) to automatically set the correct time.

It is more the client's date/time you should worry about since this is set by your users and can be wrong all the time. If you need to trust the time on client and need it to be reliable and comparable for several users, then retrieve the time from your server and account for latency, if need be.

Comment: I agree with Matthias. To double-check the server, I've added code that ran when a server app launched, to get the time from a reliable source and compare to the server's computer clock. If too much of a gap, I raise an alert, send email, or some such. For long-running app, write a daemon that sleeps most of the time and once in a while wakes to run that same check. If you have access to the server, verify it is correctly obtaining the current time from another source simply by setting its clock incorrectly and then waiting to see if it self corrects (but do so at an appropriate time).

Comment: [Get current time](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/4215/get-the-time-from-nist.gov) from United States government, National Institute of Standards and Technology. Example: `curl -s time.nist.gov:13`